# Getting warning when 2 models inherit the same object in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have object like below:

```
class FriendshipLike(object):
__table_args__ = (
    db.UniqueConstraint('requesting_user_id', 'accepting_user_id', 'status',
                        name='unique_friendship'),
)
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
date = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False,
                 default=datetime.datetime.now())

@declared_attr
def requesting_user_id(cls):
    return db.Column('requesting_user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'user.id'), nullable=False)

@declared_attr
def accepting_user_id(cls):
    return db.Column('accepting_user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'),
                     nullable=False)
```

and two models as below:

```
class Friendship(FriendshipLike, db.Model, CRUDMixin):
__tablename__ = 'friendship'

class Flirt(FriendshipLike, db.Model, CRUDMixin):
__tablename__ = 'flirt'
```

I am getting a warning

> SAWarning: Column 'requesting_user_id' on table Table('friendship', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', Integer(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('date', DateTime(), table=, nullable=False, default=ColumnDefault(datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 15, 10, 0, 47, 646868))), Column('status', Enum('accepted', 'pending', 'following', 'denied'), table=, nullable=False, default=ColumnDefault('pending')), Column('requesting_user_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=, nullable=False), Column('accepting_user_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=, nullable=False), schema=None) being replaced by Column('requesting_user_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('user.id'), table=, nullable=False), which has the same key.  Consider use_labels for select() statements.

Is there any way to make this warning go? or I should not be worried as its just giving me warning so that I should be careful while making `SELECT` statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root of the problem is the `__table_args__` attribute that is shared between `FriendshipLike` and its subclasses. That too should be a `declared_attr`, or else the `Table` instances of subclasses using the mixin will try and share the same `UniqueConstraint` object, which seems to cause all kinds of weird behaviour. Simply turn that in to a `declared_attr`

```
class FriendshipLike(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return (
            db.UniqueConstraint('requesting_user_id',
                                'accepting_user_id',
                                'status',
                                name='unique_friendship'),
        )

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False,
                     default=datetime.datetime.now())

    @declared_attr
    def requesting_user_id(cls):
        return db.Column('requesting_user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
            'user.id'), nullable=False)

    @declared_attr
    def accepting_user_id(cls):
        return db.Column('accepting_user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'),
                         nullable=False)
```

and the warnings go away. There's an example of defining indexes in mixins [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#creating-indexes-with-mixins). Note that you do not need to explicitly name the `Column` objects returned by the `declared_attr` attributes, since [a column is automatically named after the attribute it is assigned to](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html#defining-attributes).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time and explaining :) Great answer.

Comment: If I could upvote this a 100 times I would, this has been frustrating me for a while now.